# Getting the selected text in an Angular app

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Having looked at a few tutorials on how to get the selected text in an Angular project, the following snippet is always used, but when I include it in my component, I get errors:

```
getSelection() {

    let text = "";

    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }

    return text;
}
```

The first red underline error is `Object is possibly 'null'`.
The other three are `Property 'selection' does not exist on type 'Document'`.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reference in your html using @ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('contentEditable') public el: ElementRef;
```

create range (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

```
this.el.nativeElement.focus();
const sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(this.rangeClone);
```

And get selection

```
let range = document.createRange();
range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
this.rangeClone = range.cloneRange();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. That method is part of my service. Are you saying it should be in my component code? Is the code you have included supposed to replace the code in my method?

Comment: yes, it should be in component, instead of using your method, use the logic I sent